# Android method is not running

Tags: java, android, events, eventtrigger, fileobserver

It has been a long time since I stopped by this problem: my FileObserver's onEvent method is not triggered, tested, and not even the "method entered" toast is being displayed.

```
FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/Screenshots") {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "method entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (event == FileObserver.CREATE) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

fileObserver.startWatching();
```

Help me please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check existence of file prev, it should cause issue.

> public void startWatching ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Start watching for events. The monitored file or
>   directory must exist at this time, or else no events will be reported
>   (even if it appears later). If monitoring is already started, this
>   call has no effect.

Comment: I double checked it. It's a static system library.